# Tmux - disable mouse wheel in status bar

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to disable the switching of windows by scrolling in the status bar without disabling mouse altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The relevant default key bindings are (from `tmux list-keys`):

```
bind-key    -T root         WheelUpStatus     previous-window
bind-key    -T root         WheelDownStatus   next-window
```

To unbind them permanently, add the following lines to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key -T root WheelUpStatus
unbind-key -T root WheelDownStatus
```

Keep in mind the file is parsed when tmux server starts. To affect the already running server do one of the following:

- reload the altered file in tmux:
  <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source-file ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- reload the altered file by invoking tmux client in a shell:

  ```
  tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
  ```
- type the commands in tmux:
  <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`unbind-key -T root WheelUpStatus`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
  <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`unbind-key -T root WheelDownStatus`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- pass the commands by invoking tmux client in a shell:

  ```
  tmux unbind-key -T root WheelUpStatus
  tmux unbind-key -T root WheelDownStatus
  ```